# Virtual Functions and its overhead

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I came across this question and wanted to know what the answer would be ?

> Which of the following options describe the expected overhead of class
>   that has five virtual functions ?
>
> A. Every object of the class holds the address of a structure holding
>   the address of the 5 virtual functions
>
> B. Every object of the class holds the address of the five virtual
>   functions
>
> C. Every object of the class holds the address of the next virtual
>   function.
>
> D.Every object of the class holds the address of the link list object
>   that holds the address of the virtual functions.
>
> E.Every object of the class holds the address of the class declaration
>   in memory through which virtual function calls are resolved.

I am familiar with the virtual tables , that each class has a virtual table that indicates which virtual function points to which implementation . However i am not sure how instances of classes communicate with that virtual table. My guess would be A. Please let me know if I am right/wrong and also some explanation to the answer .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/203136/1611055: `Each object (that belongs to a class with at least one virtual function) has a pointer, called a vptr.  It points to the vtbl of its actual class`. The answer also says that this is not part of the standard, so different compilers **might** implement it differently. However, answer "A" would be the one which matches the linked answer

Comment: Thanks Andreas could you put that down as the answer please

Comment: You can eliminate two options because they make no sense whatsoever; and two more (for any sensible implementation) which scale badly for large numbers of virtual functions and/or objects. That leaves one sensible option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think officially the standard does not specify how the V-table is implemented, but i would also say its answer A.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf

Section 10.3 doesn't specify any specific implementation.

From section 10.3
"The virtual specifier implies membership, so a virtual function cannot be a nonmember (7.1.2)
function. Nor can a virtual function be a static member, since a virtual function call relies on a specific object for determining which function to invoke"

No more than that.